# Getting a live image (PHLivePhoto) when in a sharing extension using the Photos app

Tags: swift, ios14, share-extension, phlivephoto

I'm using a method that starts like this:

```
    static func getMediaAssets(item: NSItemProvider, completion: @escaping (Result<UploadableMediaAssets, Error>) -> ()) {
        guard item.canLoadObject(ofClass: PHLivePhoto.self) else {
            logger.error("Could not load PHLivePhoto")
            completion(.failure(LiveImageItemProviderError.cannotGetLivePhoto))
            return
        }
        
        item.loadObject(ofClass: PHLivePhoto.self) { livePhoto, error in
            guard let livePhoto = livePhoto as? PHLivePhoto else {
                logger.debug("No live photo!")
                completion(.failure(LiveImageItemProviderError.cannotGetLivePhoto))
                return
            }
            
            let assetResources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: livePhoto)
            guard assetResources.count == 2 else {
                completion(.failure(LiveImageItemProviderError.cannotGetLivePhoto))
                return
            }
            
            let filteredForMovie = assetResources.filter {$0.uniformTypeIdentifier == movieUTI}

            guard filteredForMovie.count == 1 else {
                logger.error("Could not find movie resource: \(movieUTI)")
                completion(.failure(LiveImageItemProviderError.cannotGetLivePhoto))
                return
            }
            
            let movie:PHAssetResource = filteredForMovie[0]
            
            let filteredForOther = assetResources.filter {$0 !== movie}
            
            guard filteredForOther.count == 1 else {
                logger.error("Could not find other resource")
                completion(.failure(LiveImageItemProviderError.cannotGetLivePhoto))
                return
            }
            let image: PHAssetResource = filteredForOther[0]

            let pickedImageType: ImageType

            // more code ...
   }
```

to get a live photo using the `PHPickerViewController` from my main app. That's working fine.

However, when I try to use this same method in a sharing extension to get a photo from the Photo's app, both `item.canLoadObject` and `item.loadObject` fail.

To be more clear on this point, for  "a sharing extension to get a photo from the Photo's app", I have a sharing extension (a `UIViewController`) that uses the following code:

```
        let attachments = (self.extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem)?.attachments ?? []
        
        guard attachments.count == 1 else {
            completion(.failure(HandleSharedFileError.notJustOneFile))
            return
        }
```

Using that `NSItemProvider`, attachment, I invoke my `getMediaAssets` method.

I go into the Photos app, select a live photo, use my app from the list of sharing extensions, and it invokes my sharing extension.

This is what I'm currently using in the Info.plist to select files received by the share extension:

```
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
                <string>SUBQUERY (
              extensionItems,
              $extensionItem,
              SUBQUERY (
                  $extensionItem.attachments,
                  $attachment,
                  ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "com.apple.live-photo"
              ).@count == $extensionItem.attachments.@count and $extensionItem.attachments.@count == 1
            ).@count == 1</string>
        </dict>
```

Any suggestions?

--- Updates ----

1. The error from `loadObject` (if I comment out the `canLoadObject` check) is:

> 2020-12-27T15:18:40-0700 debug  : No live photo: Optional(Error
> Domain=NSItemProviderErrorDomain Code=-1200 "Could not coerce an item
> to class PHLivePhoto" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not
> coerce an item to class PHLivePhoto})

2. With this UTI

   static let livePhotoUTI = "com.apple.live-photo"

This returns true:

```
item.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(livePhotoUTI)
```

in the sharing extension (where `item` is the `NSItemProvider`).

3. Additional reference supporting idea that live images can't be accessed from sharing extensions: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/22132?login=true&page=1#654410022

Comment: What does "a sharing extension to get a photo from the Photo's app" mean? How would a PHLivePhoto make its way to your share extension?

Comment: Just added a few more details. Thanks.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So you are assuming that when the Photos app is used to pass an image to a share extension, if that image corresponds to a live photo, the live photo is what is passed. I would suggest that perhaps that assumption is wrong.

Comment: It works in the main app, i.e., when I'm using the `PHPickerViewController`. Does this mean that I can't get a live photo in the sharing extension or I need to use a different method to get it? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what "can't get" means. This is all out of your hands. What the Photos app hands over to a share extension is totally up to the Photos app. All I'm saying is that I would not be surprised if the Photos app's idea of what to hand to a share extension is a UIImage rather than a PHLivePhoto. Perhaps this depends on what sorts of thing the share extension has declared itself willing to receive (you have not told us anything about that), but even then I'd not be surprised if a PHLivePhoto failed to make its way directly out of the Photos app like that.

Comment: Just added a note about what I'm using in the Info.plist. Why would you `not be surprised if a PHLivePhoto failed to make its way directly out of the Photos app like that`?

Comment: Well, image files are common coin, but never in my life have I seen one app hand a Live Photo to another app.

Comment: I have submitted this as Feedback Assistant bug FB8975010 to Apple.

Comment: Still I doubt it’s a bug. There isn’t really such a thing as a Live Photo.  It’s a video along with a representative photo.

Comment: Sure. I realize that. Still would like to know how to get access to it from a sharing extension. I can do it fine from my main app.